# How do I get PyLint to find namespace packages?

Tags: python, namespaces, pylint

I have a virtualenv where I've installed two packages, both using the `company.project_name` namespace. So the first package is importable from `company.project_name.one` and the second from `company.project_name.two`.

The challenge is that I can't seem to be able to run PyLint on either one of them. If I issue:

```
$ pylint company.project_name.one
```

I get:

```
************* Module company.project_name.one
F:  1, 0: No module named project_name.one(fatal)
```

I suspect that I'm probably doing something wrong. Is there a proper way to do this?

Edit: I should have made it clear that `company.project_name` and `company` are namespace packages and not regular packages.

Comment: Are you missing \_\_init\_\_.py files in directories? "The \_\_init\_\_.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages" https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: The \_\_init\_\_.py files are present in the source tree. For both `company` and `company.project_name` they only use the `__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)` line. However, I checked the virtualenv site-packages directory and they aren't there. It seems that when pip installs them into site-packages, it removes them and puts a .pth file in there that supposedly declares the namespaces instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pylint company/project_name/one.py` from the command line

```
~$ pylint foo2.foo.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module foo2.foo.py
F:  1, 0: No module py in foo2.foo (fatal)

~$ pylint foo2/foo.py

No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module foo2.foo
C:  1, 0: Black listed name "foo" (blacklisted-name)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  1, 0: Invalid argument name "a" (invalid-name)
C:  1, 0: Invalid argument name "b" (invalid-name)
W:  1,13: Unused argument 'a' (unused-argument)
W:  1,16: Unused argument 'b' (unused-argument)


Report
======
3 statements analysed.

etc............
```

There is no directory `company.` no you need to use `/` as you would if you were changing to a directory `cd foo2/`

Comment: My problem seems to stem from the fact that `company.project_name` is a namespace package and not a regular package. As a result even if I pass the location of the package directly as above, I still get import-error reports for sub-packages in the namespace package when it tries to lint the file: `E: 15, 0: No name 'project_name' in module 'company' (no-name-in-module)` and `F: 15, 0: Unable to import 'company.project_name.one.model' (import-error)`. I'm thinking that there's a special step I need to take for namespace packages that I'm missing.

Comment: what happens when you run it on company?

Comment: Still the same errors, even though it eventually lints some of the very same modules it gives (import-error) for.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I it appears that PyLint doesn't really like namespace packages declared in this way:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

I changed it to the following and it all works just fine:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: this sounds like a bug, could you please submit an issue about that on the astroid project? (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/astroid/issues)

Comment: @tjd.rodgers Unfortunately, this doesn't work on the latest version of setuptools which requires that you must call `declare_namespace`.